# IntelliJ IDEA Maven, doesn't recognize Jackson dependency

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I'm trying to use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to handle my files. However, for some reason, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize the dependency, despite having that added in file *[pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F)*.

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

A screenshot is below:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code (which should be a [mcve]) *as text*.

Comment: I think Intellij can be quite sluggish at times. I noticed this with Jackson too. Closing and reopening the project often helped, as a "Maven -> Reload project" didn't help either. I always do an ```mvn clear install``` from the terminal and have no more problems.

Comment: I've seen this in SBT too. I have no idea why it happens. Suspecting an IDE bug - it must use Jackson internally.

Answer (score 2):

Try to force IntelliJ to reload the dependencies. Right-click on `pom.xml` and select "Maven -> Reload project". Like this:

[image]

At least that should give you an error if IntelliJ for whatever reason can not resolve the dependency.